# Is there a way for my Spring backend to tell my ReactJS client application which component within it's project it will render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I have a Java REST API backend.

I would like to know if it's possible for it to response to my client something that would tell him what component within it's project it will use for rendering.

My current idea is to get a string from the server, and use it's string in render to decide which component.

I am using webpack for building my app, does this mean I will have to import my component using a `require` call ? (I don't think ES6 import can work here).

Is there a cleaner way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by **showing a loading screen** while **fetching the response from the api**. And based on the response, you would trigger a route change in your app to the component you want.

Instead, if you are interested in server-side rendering, check [this example repo](https://github.com/winterbe/spring-react-example)

Comment: I would rather do it in the constructor of a parent component than associating it in the router.

Comment: I am looking for idea's of implementation, I can't implement it right now this must come after